# Can anyone explain why this text sits below the img, and not beside it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap 3, heres the snippit from the navbar. Both are in a span so should be inline?

```
<a href="#">
    <span><img src="images/brand/pgblocks-logo-white-nostrap.png" class="brand-img img-responsive"></span>
    <span><h3>test test</h3></span>
</a>
```

Comment: but `h3` is block element and `.img-responsive` has `display:block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  this

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <span><img src="#"/></span>
            Logo Title
        </a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```css
span img {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
    <span><img src="https://www.ucl.ac.uk/prospective-students/graduate/images/test/placeholder-200x200"></span>
    <span><h3>test test</h3></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `h3` is a block element.

```html
<a href="#">
    <span><img src="images/brand/pgblocks-logo-white-nostrap.png" class="brand-img img-responsive"></span>
    <span><h3>... Because h3 is a block element</h3></span>
</a>


<a href="#">
    <span><img src="images/brand/pgblocks-logo-white-nostrap.png" class="brand-img img-responsive"></span>
    <span>Span is an inline element</span>
</a>
```